# Error running mysql script through Docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a docker container that will run a mysql script which generates a database and then table. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mysql:latest


WORKDIR /


ADD . /


EXPOSE 3306

CMD mysql -u "root" -proot < "schema.sql"
```

However when I run it I get the following error messages:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I run the sql script I only get the password error.  Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Like majority of official docker image, you can configure the container through the entrypoint.

It's documented on [mysql docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). You can use `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_DATABASE`, `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD` to configure mysql instance.

You will set this variables through environments variables with `-e` with `docker` or `environments` option in `docker-compose.yml` file.

You can see in [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L177) that files(.sh,.sql,.sql.gz) copied in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ image will be run during startup.

So you can write Dockerfile like this :

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
# No need to override CMD default command of mysql image
```